# Improving cube engine performance

Tags: java, opengl

Right now I'm using basic immediate mode to render out 4096 cubes with face culling on. I get an average of 50 fps with or without face culling. Why do I get the same fps with it enabled as when it is disabled? What else could I do to increase performance? Also, should I use indexed VBOs to render out the cubes? And does anyone know of a good VBO tutorial (preferably for Java in LWJGL).

Comment: Are you using a texture atlas?  Frustum culling?  How is your render loop structured?  Do you do a `PushMatrix/Translate/DrawCube/PopMatrix` per cube?

Comment: Are you sure that your fps is not locked to 50? What's the fps if you draw a single cube?

Comment: Disable vsync and you will see the actual FPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate mode is rather slow for a large amount of geometry.I have personally never bench-marked but that is what I read in different resources and here from OpenGL gurus.Also it makes sense as using programmable pipeline you don't need to push vertex data to GPU on each frame as you work with buffers.So I would suggest you first moving to the modern OpenGL as it is both fast and much more powerful than the old fixed implementation.You will have a lot of flexibility using buffers and shaders.Now, for you to get started I would recommend to take a look at [this](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) tutorial series.And if you want to get an idea how to write a basic render engine you can take a look at [this](http://nopper.tv/graphicsengine.html) open source project which feature very simple OpenGL 4.0 based rendering system.It is C++ and not Java but the API is the same as that of LWJGL.Only buffer creation is different as far as I remember from my personal experience with LWJGL .
Also,if you want LWJGL modern OpenGL tutorial, [here](https://code.google.com/r/zaphosmatthewnicholls-opengl-superbible-java/) is a nice resource which is based on the OpenGL SuperBible 5 book code base.And [this](https://github.com/integeruser/gltut-lwjgl) one is the LWJGL port of the above mentioned Modern OpenGL tutorial by Jason L. McKesson .Hope it helps.

Comment: This is amazing, thanks! I think I've had the most trouble with 3D VBOs and how to render multiple cubes. For example, I have one cube stored in a VBO, but I can't figure out how to put that In a for loop so it renders out a bunch.

Comment: Just go through the tutorials I put here. Everything you need is there  :)

Comment: With VAOs and instancing you can draw 1 million cubes at 50FPS on a 580 GTX.